# VSCode debug adapter not calling launchRequest

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to learn the debugger API and decided to try to write a debugger extension for the SBCL debugger as practice. I'm not sure why all my code does is call initializeRequest and disconnectRequest.

Here's what I have in my package.json

```
        "debuggers": [
            {
                "type": "common-lisp",
                "label": "Common Lisp REPL",
                "initialConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "type": "common-lisp",
                        "name": "Common Lisp REPL",
                        "request": "launch"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
```

My Factory class is defined in its own module,

```
const { DebugAdapterInlineImplementation } = require('vscode');

module.exports.Factory = class {
    createDebugAdapterDescriptor(session) {
        return new DebugAdapterInlineImplementation(new Session());
    }
};
```

My Session class is in its own module,

```
const { LoggingDebugSession } = require('vscode-debugadapter');

module.exports.Session = class extends LoggingDebugSession {
    constructor() {
        super('common-lisp-debug.txt');
    }

    initializeRequest(response, args) {
        console.log('initializeRequest');

        response.body = {
            supportsConfigurationDoneRequest: true,
        };

        this.sendResponse(response);
    }

    disconnectRequest(response, args) {
        console.log('disconnectRequest');
    }

    configurationDoneRequest(response, args) {
        console.log('configurationDoneRequest');
        super.configurationDoneRequest(response, args);
    }

    launchRequest(response, args) {
        console.log('launchRequest');
        this.sendResponse(response);
    }
};
```

My extension.js has this code in the activation call,

```
    const factory = new Factory();
    ctx.subscriptions.push(vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterDescriptorFactory('common-lisp', factory));
    if ('dispose' in factory) {
        ctx.subscriptions.push(factory);
    }
```

I start debugging my extension, which brings up the EDH window. I create a debug configuration, which does what it's supposed to and creates this launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "common-lisp",
            "name": "Common Lisp REPL",
            "request": "launch"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start the debugger from there, I see initializeRequest get printed but nothing else. The debug window has the blue dot progress thing going across it in a loop indefinitely. When I click stop debugging, I see disconnectRequest get printed.

Why are configurationDoneRequest and launchRequest not getting called? Also, where does the LoggingDebugSession put the log file?

Update: when I start the debugger, the CPU usage jumps to 35% so it's doing something. When I hit pause, almost every time it stops here in timers.js

```
  function processTimers(now) {
    debug('process timer lists %d', now); // Debugger pauses on this line
    nextExpiry = Infinity;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although my debug adapter server is written in Java. It turned out I did not send the `initialized` event during/after the `initialize` request, see the part about the [initialized event](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Events_Initialized) in the DAP documentation.

Edit: The specs state that the `initialized` event must be sent *after* the `initialize` request. Sending it from the `attach` request is acceptable for VSCode.